# Not able to configure url pattern for Django views

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Whenever, I made a request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/?id=23 got this error:`

```
The current URL, contact/, didn't match any of these.
```

Views.py

```
def generate_data(request, contact):
    number = request.GET.get('contact', '')
    return str(resp)
```

url.py

```
url(r'^data/(?P<contact>\w+)$', 'myapp.views.generate_data', name='generating data'),
```

There is no `template` for `views.py`. I tried to change the `url pattern` according to `django` official documentation but didn't get succeed.

Comment: Urlpatterns should end in a slash `/`. You're urlpattern matches `/data/something/` not `/contact/`

Comment: @BogdanIulianBursuc didn't get you. Could you please write the URL pattern?

Comment: Try to access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/contact?id=23`

Comment: So you want to match /contact/ right and contact to be pased to the view?

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
url(r'^data/(?P<contact>\w+)/$', 'myapp.views.generate_data', name='generating data'),
```

and you do a request to

```
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/< contact_id >
```